# Ruby on Rails - AbstractController::DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i try to add to my create-method one redirect to my support tickets. But always i get an

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError

But i need this redirect after the upload of the file. How can i fix this ?

Upload-controller :

```
def create

   @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

      respond_to do |format|
          if @upload.save
           format.html {
             render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
             :content_type => 'text/html',
             :layout => false
           }

           format.json { render json: {files: [@upload.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @upload }

        else
           format.html { render action: "new" }
           format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
        redirect_to new_support_ticket_path
     end
end
```

upload.rb :

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :upload
  has_attached_file :upload

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }

  end

end
```

Comment: Try commenting  redirect_to new_support_ticket_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't allow you to `redirect_to` after `render`. I think `redirect_to new_support_ticket_path` should be placed in format.html block because you need to `redirect_to` in html view.

@upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

```
  respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
       format.html {
         redirect_to new_support_ticket_path
       }

       format.json { render json: {files: [@upload.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @upload }

    else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

try using return command after redirect

Answer (score 0):

Neither `render` nor `redirect` stops the execution of the controller action. And you can't have both `render` and `redirect` in the same action. Thats what the error says. Since you're already rendering a view, remove the `redirect` at the end of the controller action.

```
def create

 @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

  respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
       format.html {
         render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
         :content_type => 'text/html',
         :layout => false
       }

       format.json { render json: {files: [@upload.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @upload }

    else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end
```

For more, search for **Avoiding Double Render Errors** in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render